passing a shared_ptr to a function from another function
I'm returning to C++ after a long time, having inherited a code-base, a part of which has the structure in the following code. I have two objects, Wrapped and Wrapper and as might be expected, Wrapper wraps Wrapped. There are two factory methods make_Wrapper and make_Wrapped which return pointers to corresponding objects.
In the following code, I have observed that Case1 in which I use a shared_ptr does not work, whereas Case2 in which I use a normal C++ pointer works. By "does not work", I mean that the value nz_=10 in wrapped is replaced by junk in Case1 whereas it is equal to 10 in Case2. I can check this by printing the value of wrapper.nz_ in main via outside_wrapper->print().
I think this is because the object pointed to by the shared_ptr is deleted after this function make_Wrapper exits. Am I correct?
What is the right way to pass a object via shared_ptr from make_Wrapper to the  Wrapper constructor?
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

// this is struct which is to be wrapped
struct Wrapped {
  int nz_;
  Wrapped(int nz):nz_(nz) {}
  inline virtual void destroy() { delete this; };
};

// this is the wrapper
struct Wrapper {
  Wrapper(Wrapped& wrapped):wrapped_(wrapped){}
  Wrapped& wrapped_;
  
  inline virtual void destroy() { delete this; };
  
  void print() {
    std::cout << "from wrapper: wrapped_.nz_=" << wrapped_.nz_<<std::endl;
  }
};

// factory function which returns pointer to wrapped object
Wrapped* make_Wrapped(int nz) {
  return new Wrapped(nz);
}


// factory function which returns pointer to wrapper object
Wrapper* make_Wrapper(int nz) {

  // Case 1
  // following line does not work - I think the object pointed to by the shared_ptr is deleted after this function exits
  std::shared_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped(make_Wrapped(nz), std::mem_fun(&Wrapped::destroy));

  // Case 2
  // following line works
  // Wrapped *wrapped = new Wrapped(nz);
  
  std::cout<<" from make_Wrapper "<<(*wrapped).nz_<<std::endl;
  return new Wrapper(*wrapped);
}

int main() {
    int nz=10;
    char tempbuffer[80];
    
    std::shared_ptr<Wrapper> outside_wrapper(make_Wrapper(nz), std::mem_fun(&Wrapper::destroy));
    outside_wrapper->print();

    std::cout << "Enter something to continue ..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> tempbuffer;
    return 0;
}



What does "does not work" and "works as expected" mean? Do you get any error? If yes, post them. If you don't get any error, then explain what is expected output and how does it differ from current output.

The value nz_=10 in wrapped is replaced by junk in Case1 whereas it is equal to 10 in Case2

Add this also to your question.

Why do you deal with raw pointers (and manual new/delete) at all ? The whole point of using smart pointers is to avoid all that.

I used raw pointers because I couldn't get smart pointers to work and because that was the way I learned C++ in stone age. Would appreciate any guidance to get smart pointers to work.

Use unique_ptr the way @wohlstad showed in their answer. The first choice should be unique_ptr (except ofcourse when shared ownership is needed) as given in that answer.

In my experience, having a destroy method that does a delete this; is a C++ anti-pattern that comes from a naïve porting C++ code from another language, where that other language uses an idiomatic alloc-init-destroy-free pattern.  The init should be in the constructor, the destroy should be in the destructor.  No delete this;. (There another C++ anti-pattern that does two-phase construct then later init.)

@Eljay or you are doing anything across allocator boundaries (ie: plugins), where delete just won't work correctly, and will use the wrong allocator.

@AhmedAEK what do you mean ? If delete does not work, it will also not work inside destroy() which calls it, isn't it ?

@wohlstad the library that has the correct allocator will be the one generating the destroy function and populating the vtable, calling delete outside of this library would segfault with Heap corruption. calling it within destroy is safe because it is the within the same library that called new

@AhmedAEK this could be. But there's no indication for this setup (with the library etc.)  in the question.

@AhmedAEK your comment about code being partitioned into libraries is correct. I didn't mention it because of my quest to create an MRE

@NNN even if it's in a separate library, as long you build everything together and don't use special allocators, you shouldn't normally need a destory() method. But you can add it if it's really needed.

You can use a smart pointer to hold the Wrapped object inside the Wrapper. When you use smart pointers, there's no need for raw pointers and manual new/delete. There's also no need (at least by default) for an explicit destroy() method.
In the example below I used std::unique_ptr, which does not support copying, and is therefore moved instead when needed.
std::unique_ptr should be the default smart pointer to use when it is sufficient.
If you want to have shared ownership, you can use std::shared_ptr and std::make_shared instead (and then you can simply remove the std::moves).
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// this is struct which is to be wrapped
struct Wrapped {
    int nz_;
    Wrapped(int nz) :nz_(nz) {}
};

// this is the wrapper
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(std::unique_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped) :wrapped_(std::move(wrapped)) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped_;

    void print() {
        std::cout << "from wrapper: wrapped_.nz_=" << wrapped_->nz_ << std::endl;
    }
};

// factory function which returns pointer to wrapped object
std::unique_ptr<Wrapped> make_Wrapped(int nz) {
    return std::make_unique<Wrapped>(nz);
}

// factory function which returns pointer to wrapper object
std::unique_ptr<Wrapper> make_Wrapper(int nz) {
    auto wrapped = make_Wrapped(nz);
    std::cout << " from make_Wrapper " << wrapped->nz_ << std::endl;
    auto wrapper = std::make_unique<Wrapper>(std::move(wrapped));
    return wrapper;
}

int main() {
    int nz = 10;
    auto outside_wrapper = make_Wrapper(nz);
    outside_wrapper->print();
}

Output:
 from make_Wrapper 10
from wrapper: wrapped_.nz_=10

Live demo
Since you explicitly asked about std::shared_ptr,
here's also a demo with it: Live demo with std::shared_ptr.

once an object is wrapped by a shared_ptr it will be destroyed when the last shared_ptr pointing at it is destroyed, which happens at the end of make_Wrapper.
the solution:
have Wrapper store a shared_ptr instead of just a reference, now Wrapped will stay alive so long as Wrapper is alive.
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(std::shared_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped) :wrapped_(std::move(wrapped)) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped_;

    inline virtual void destroy() { delete this; };

    void print() {
        std::cout << "from wrapper: wrapped_.nz_=" << wrapped_->nz_ << std::endl;
    }
};

// factory function which returns pointer to wrapper object
Wrapper* make_Wrapper(int nz) {

    std::shared_ptr<Wrapped> wrapped(make_Wrapped(nz), std::mem_fun(&Wrapped::destroy));

    std::cout << " from make_Wrapper " << (*wrapped).nz_ << std::endl;
    return new Wrapper(std::move(wrapped));
}

